# Enterprise Mac App Distribution

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa

I have a query regarding enterprise Mac app distribution.I have signed my mac app with enterprise distribution certificate which will be valid for next three years.

Now my question is that whether apps installed on Mac os would stop working after three years or they would continue to run?

A link or suggestion would be great.

Answer (score 1):

It will continue to run but when a new installation happen on a different mac the OS will show a warning like this one:

[image]

Comment: Thanks.. can you please let us know the warning on installation?

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment.

Answer (score 0):

I found below link from Apple

[Apple's Link](https://developer.apple.com/support/developer-id/)

It says

***As long as your Developer ID certificate was valid when you compiled your app, then users can download and run your app, even after the expiration date of the certificate. However, you will need a new certificate to sign updates and new applications.***